# DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while opening socket to (Connection refused) - WSO2 APIM Key Manager

Tags: sockets, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have set up wso2 apim 2.1.0 in distributed environment. I run WSO2 servers (TrafficManager, KeyManager, Gateway, Publisher, and Store) on the same machine. When I try to up KeyManager APIM instance from key manager profile I get a connection refused error as follows.

```
[2018-02-03 20:45:51,380] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while       
opening socket to 192.168.8.100:9711. Connection refused (Connection refused) 
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while opening socket to 192.168.8.100:9711. Connection refused (Connection refused)
      at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:74)
      at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
      at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
      at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
      at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:58)
... 9 more
```

I have followed the documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Distributed+Deployment+of+API+Manager#DistributedDeploymentofAPIManager-Step3.1-ConfiguretheKeyManager. According to that, I have only changed ip and port of the `<ServerURL>` under `<APIGateway>` element. Other than that, no changes were made to apimanager.xml in KeyManager. I am not sure for what purposes the port 9711 is used in Key Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of the datapublisher connection in throttling configurations of KeyManager. The only solution i found out was to manually give ReceiverURL and AuthURL ports as 9611 and 9711.